# Jboss CLI: Expected [INT] but was STRING

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, command-line-interface

I am making CLI script to add two attributes(max-post-size, max-save-post-size) to `http connector`
so it should looks like:

```
<connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" max-post-size="5120000000" max-save-post-size="1024000000" socket-binding="http"/>
```

my command is:

```
/subsystem=web/connector=https:add(socket-binding=http,scheme=http,protocol="HTTP/1.1",max-post-size=5120000000, max-save-post-size=1024000000)
```

But it gives me

```
"failure-description" => "JBAS014688: Wrong type for max-post-size. Expected [INT] but was STRING",
```

So I am really confused how to declare integer in CLI, I try `max-post-size=[5120000000]`, `max-save-post-size=[1024000000]` but it doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given

> [standalone@localhost:9999 connector=http] cd /subsystem=web/connector=http

The type of the attribute is `INT`:

> [standalone@localhost:9999 connector=http] ls -l
>   ATTRIBUTE          VALUE      TYPE
>   [...]
>   max-post-size      2120000000 INT
>   [...]

If the value is < 2,147,483,647, it works:

> [standalone@localhost:9999 connector=http] /subsystem=web/connector=http:write-attribute(name=max-post-size, value=2120000000)
>   {
>       "outcome" => "success",
>       "response-headers" => {
>           "operation-requires-reload" => true,
>           "process-state" => "reload-required"
>       }
>   }

If the value is greater, it fails:

> [standalone@localhost:9999 connector=http] /subsystem=web/connector=http:write-attribute(name=max-post-size, value=3120000000)
>   {
>       "outcome" => "failed",
>       "failure-description" => "JBAS014688: Wrong type for max-post-size. Expected [INT] but was STRING",
>       "rolled-back" => true,
>       "response-headers" => {"process-state" => "reload-required"}
>   }

So the error message is misleading.

Comment: Thank you. But is there any way we can add/change this attribute by CLI?

Comment: @Dreamer OK, I see. Give me a moment, I'll rephrase my answer. It seems that you have hit the `int` limit.